# Python Selenium: how to click on table content when changing table page

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

url = "https://www.bungol.ca/"
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path ='/usr/local/bin/geckodriver')
driver.get(url)

#Select toronto by default
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/select/optgroup[1]/option[1]""").click()
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/section/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/div/button""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/nav/div[1]/ul[1]/li[3]/select/option[8]""").click()
#select last 2 years
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="activeListings"]""").click()


#opening sold listing in that area
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[5]/i""").click() #closes property type slide
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="navbarDropdown"]""").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="listViewToggle"]""").click()


def data_collector():
    hidden_next = driver.find_element_by_class_name("nextPaginate")
    #inputs in textbox
    inputElement = driver.find_element_by_id('navbarSearchAddressInput')
    inputElement.send_keys('M3B2B6')
    time.sleep(1)
    #inputElement.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
    row_count = 3
    table = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("""#listViewTableBody""")

    while hidden_next.is_displayed(): #while there is a next page button to be pressed

        time.sleep(3) #delay for table refresh

        #row_count = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("""html body#body div#listView.table-responsive table#listViewTable.table.table-hover.mb-0 tbody#listViewTableBody tr.mb-2"""))           
        for row in range(row_count): #loop through the rows found

            #alternate row by changing the tr index
            driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[8]/table/tbody/tr[""" + str(row + 1) + """]/td[1]""").click()
            time.sleep(2)
            print(driver.find_element_by_css_selector("""#listingStatus""").text) #sold price

            #closes the pop up after getting the data
            driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.modal-xl > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(1) > button:nth-child(1)').click()
            time.sleep(1)

        #clicks next page button for the table    
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//*[@id="listViewNextPaginate"]""").click()    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data_collector()
```

The code loops through all the rows in the first table (currently set to 3 for testing), clicks on each row - pop-up shows up, grabs the information and close the pop-up. But when it clicks to the next page, it doesn't click on any of the rows of the second page. It doesn't show an error for not finding the row xpath either. But instead shows error for the pop-window close button because the popup did not open due to not pressing on the row to display pop-up window.

How do I make it click the rows when the table flips to the next page?

for table reference:

https://www.bungol.ca/map/location/toronto/?

close the property slider on the left

click tool -> open list

Answer (score 0):

In my browser I also can't  open the pop up, when I click on the row in the second page. So I think this can be the fault of the website.

If You want check if the element exists, You can use this code:

```
def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath, driver):
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        return False
    return True
```

Comment: Yea I tried that. It seems that I need to either focus on a smaller area for smaller listing size or move use the dots on the map.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. My understanding is your script goes through the listings, opens a listing, grabs the listings status, close the listing and does the same for all the listings.

If my understanding is correct, the below code may help you. Its better to change implicit and time.sleep() to explicit wait and clean up the functions.

Having said that, I did not fully test the code, but the code did navigate to more than one page of listings and collected data

```
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
import time

driver = Firefox(executable_path=r'path to geckodriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.bungol.ca/') 
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

# Select toronto by default
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#locationChoice button[type="submit"]').click()

sold_in_the_last = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('soldInTheLast'))
sold_in_the_last.select_by_visible_text('2 Years')

driver.find_element_by_id('activeListings').click()

# opening sold listing in that area
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#leftSidebarClose>i').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('navbarDropdown').click()
driver.find_element_by_id('listViewToggle').click()

def get_listings():
    listings_table = driver.find_element_by_id('listViewTableBody')
    listings_table_rows = listings_table.find_elements_by_tag_name('tr')
    return listings_table_rows

def get_sold_price(listing):
    listing.find_element_by_css_selector('td:nth-child(1)').click()
    time.sleep(2)
    sold_price = driver.find_element_by_id('listingStatus').text

    time.sleep(2)
    close = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.modal-content>.modal-body>button[class="close"]')
    close[2].click()
    time.sleep(2)

    return sold_price

def data_collector():
    data = []
    time.sleep(2)
    next = driver.find_element_by_id('listViewNextPaginate')

    # get all the listing prior to the last page
    while next.is_displayed():
        listings = get_listings()
        for listing in listings:
            data.append(get_sold_price(listing))

        next.click()

    # get listings from last page
    listings = get_listings()
    for listing in listings:
        data.append(get_sold_price(listing))

    return data

if __name__ == '__main__':
    from pprint import pprint
    data = data_collector()
    pprint(data)
    print(len(data))
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it turns out the website was updating their database that's why I couldn't click contents on second page. It works fine now.

Comment: Great to know that. If my answer helped you in any way, you can always accept my answer. Have a good one